# How to change talkback instructions for double tap to activate for RemoteView used in widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget, talkback, accessibility

I am using a custom layout for RemoteView in widget. In talkback , it is currently speaking "double tap to activate" on imageview. But i want to replace the text with "double tap to open app". How can i get the above behavior in widgets?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with the current APIs. `RemoteViews` don't have methods to set `AccessibilityNodeInfo`.

Workaround would be to add this information to content description via [RemoteViews#setContentDescription](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setContentDescription(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). Then the user would still receive the information as "Open app, double tap to activate"